# wxPython - button animation slows down computer

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making a wx app in which a button is supposed to go into a looped animation when clicked. The background color is what's being animated on the button. It runs fine for a couple of minutes but then the app starts to become unresponsive after a couple of minutes and even crashes the computer sometimes.
It's important for the application's use that the animation be able to run for very long periods of time. I'm using a timer to perform the animation. I've tried routinely clearing the dc, using different frame rates and double buffering and I get the same result every time.

My code is below:

```
import wx
import os

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class LbDisplay(wx.Frame):
    sixon = False
    sevenon = False
    eighton = False
    nineon = False
    tenon = False
    elevenon = False
    ID_TIMER = 1
    Speed = 1
    red = 255
    anim = 'down'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: LbDisplay.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.NO_BORDER | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, LbDisplay.ID_TIMER)
        self.button_6 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_7 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_8 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_9 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_10 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_11 = wx.Button(self, -1, "")
        self.button_11.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.close)
        self.button_6.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.change_six)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.blink, id=LbDisplay.ID_TIMER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: LbDisplay.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("LbDisplay")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: LbDisplay.__do_layout

        self.SetMinSize(wx.GetDisplaySize())
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(6, 1, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_6, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_7, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_8, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_9, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_10, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_11, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
        grid_sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade
    def change_six(self, e):
        if LbDisplay.sixon == False:
            LbDisplay.sixon = True
            self.timer.Start(LbDisplay.Speed)
        else:
            self.button_6.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(223, 220, 217, 0))
            self.timer.Stop()
            LbDisplay.sixon = False

    def close(self,e):
        os._exit(True)

    def blink(self,e):
        if LbDisplay.anim == 'down':
            LbDisplay.red -= 1
            self.button_6.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(LbDisplay.red,0,0))
            if LbDisplay.red <= 56:
                LbDisplay.anim = 'up'
        if LbDisplay.anim == 'up':
            LbDisplay.red += 1
            self.button_6.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(LbDisplay.red,0,0))
            if LbDisplay.red >= 255:
                LbDisplay.anim = 'down'
    def OnPaint(self, e):
        self.dc = wx.PaintDC(self)




# end of class LbDisplay
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    LbDisplay = LbDisplay(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(LbDisplay)
    LbDisplay.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. If you'll observe the above code you'll notice that the timer is using a refresh rate of 300fps. I don't even think a GPU can do much more than 60fps, and this is running straight on the cpu. Lol! 
 Reducing it to 20fps did the trick. Now it can run all day without a hitch.